# Codeigniter subdomains and WAMP

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, wamp

Im trying to do something [like this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/) .
Basically i want to:

- When you access domain.com it should load: domain.com/frontend
- When you access userlogin.domain.com it should load: domain.com/backend/userlogin

The nettus shows how to this on wamp but using different directories for each case.
For example, if you access domain.com the folder set in apache virtualhosts is: c:/folder_of_frontend, if you access userlogin.domain.com the folder is set to c:/folder_of_backend

I want to use the same CI system and application folder. I'll instead use different controllers to handle front and backend.

Thanks

Comment: Wild-card sub domain that points to the same /code/path as your actual domain with some rewrite trickery. I'm trying to figure the same thing out and this is as far as I've gotten.

Comment: hey @dogmatic69. Can you post what you have so far? I dont want to redirect, i want to route. Thanks.

Comment: well, just what that tutorial had you linked. except both the vhosts go to the same place. also I said nothing about redirecting, rewriting is 'routing' the request to another place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a constant determined by $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and then switch or set other variables based on the value of the constant.

```
$subdomain = str_replace(".mydomain.com","",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if (!empty($subdomain) && $subdomain != 'www')
{
    define('SUBDOMAIN',$subdomain);
}
else
{
    define('SUBDOMAIN',NULL);
}
```

Elsewhere in your application you can then check for the value of SUBDOMAIN and perform appropriate actions.

//edit.. I'd usually put the above in /index.php but /application/config/constants.php might also be a good place. Think I've just picked up a bad habbit there.

Comment: Before getting on any php, i need to rewrite the url to make it work. I think the first step here is make the .htaccess work

Comment: After all  it actually worked. I check your constant and i load the the controller i want in the routes file. So far, no .htaccess trickery. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, shouldn't need any .htaccess. Just wild-card the subdomain in your hosts, point everything to the same CI install, then do the above.

I've used a similar method in the past to run multiple sites from the same codebase. Selecting a different database or whatever's needed based on the domain or sub-domain.